# Database schema for products with categories MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a products table as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_store_products` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `is_featured` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `promotion_sale`  tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `current_price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `original_price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `parent_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `sub_parent_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `child_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `instock_quantity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `sold_quantity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `list_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `reviewed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `store_id` (`store_id`),
     KEY `parent_cat` (`parent_category`),
     KEY `sub_parent_cat` (`sub_parent_category`),
     KEY `category` (`child_category`),
     FULLTEXT KEY `product_title` (`title`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

As you can see I have 5 indices. 3 of them are for the product category. I did this in order to make the product available fast in parent category, sub categoy and child category. The category depth is always 3.

For example if a product titled **Women Fashion Heels** is in `Fashion > Women Shoes > Heels`

Currently I am using these queries to get products when a user clicks any link from the breadcrumbs

```
//Heels category id = 10
SELECT title, current_price, description FROM tbl_store_products WHERE category = 10
```

or

```
//Women Shoes category id = 8
SELECT title, current_price, description FROM tbl_store_products WHERE sub_parent_category = 8
```

or

```
//Fashion category id = 4
SELECT title, current_price, description FROM tbl_store_products WHERE parent_category = 4
```

And I find the product in all levels of categories just fine. But I feel I created too many indices. Can anyone suggest me a better way of doing this. Also I would appreciate it if anyone can tell me other recommendations regarding other issues with my table. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably not what I would do, but I don't think we could tell that it was wrong - and, more generally, your model seems OK to me. You might want to take a look at materialized paths and/or nested sets.

Comment: Tnx. I will check paths. I tried nested sets but i found it really complicated to make changes to categories tree.